# Unexpected NullPointerException while creating properties file?

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception

The code is very simple : If the properties file doesn't exist, it has to be created (Java JDK1.6 , Swing):

```
try {
           //loads the properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("Config/prop.properties"));               

    } catch (IOException ex) {
            // if properties doesn't exist yet : create it.
        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("Config/prop.properties"), null);
    }
```

This has worked for more than 2 months without ever giving errors. I recently did a minor update to the application (completely unrelated to this code), and it suddenly gives NullpointerExceptions :

- If the file doesn't exist, it gives the error at the 'prop.store' command, but the file is still created!
- If the file exists, it gives an error at the load command.

Does anyone have an idea how such a thing is possible? How can this code suddenly stop working?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `prop` maybe `null`? Have you tried debugging it to see where the NPE actually gets thrown?

Comment: Can you post the stack traces?

Comment: @user714965 Yes indeed, prop = null when creating it.
I really feel ashamed of my question now... I had 3 properties file that I instantiated like : "public Properties recov, prop, opt = new Properties();" , so the first two were indeed 'null'. 
Thanks for pointing the obvious out!

Comment: Post the line where you declare `prop`, i think you maybe didn't do `new Properties()` as you were said before.